# Regex match tangled expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

> abcabca

and this regex:

```
/abca/g
```

this one only matchs the first `abca` but I want it to match the second one too.

Comment: You mean repeated `abc` ? How about `/(abc)\1/g` ?

Comment: What is the rule? Not at the start?

Comment: I mean, I want to match two 'abca's... this is a link to test https://regex101.com/r/fO8rQ0/11

Comment: Where is the second `abca` in your string ? It's only `abca` followed by `bca`.

Comment: [abc(a]bca)  ==> 2 abca: the first one is delimited by [ ] and the second one by ( )

Comment: @Burawi: Do you mean [like this](https://regex101.com/r/fO8rQ0/12) ?

Comment: @noob: what you did matchs 'abca' and 'bca' and I want it to match 'abca' and 'abca', that's ok I found a solution in the best answer and thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a lookahead for overlapped matches:

```
/(?=(abca))/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pV2fT9/1)

Comment: What?? are you serious about **Look ahead doesn't work in JavaScript** Did you check my demo?

Comment: @dev-null: **Look Behind** doesn't work in Javascript.

Comment: @anubhava: How is this **matching** ? It's just positioning regex pointer before `abc`. A little explanation as to what is done will be helpful.

Comment: Beware, this pattern always matches an empty string, which causes the `lastIndex` property *not* to update when matching within a loop. You may either increment it yourself or work around this by including a character in the match `/(?=(abca))./g`

Comment: @noob it's actually capturing the "match" into group `1` instead of group `0`.

Answer (score 1):

[Anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35186985/3832970) is incomplete because as [Lucas Trzesniewski mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186928/regex-match-tangled-expressions/35186985#comment58091778_35186985), the `/(?=(abca))/g` regex needs specific JS code to work with.

If you test the regex at [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3cnjq), you will get a warning:

[image]

That happens because the match is an empty string, the `abca` value is a *submatch*, a captured text. In order for the regex index to advance, you need to tell JS to move on along the string:

```js
var re = /(?=(abca))/g; 
var str = 'abcabca';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {   // Here we tell the regex
        re.lastIndex++;               // engine to move 
    }                                 // on
    res.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/fW0pB1/1)

*Conclusions:*

- **Use [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) to test your regexps, and make use of its code generator feature**
- JS multiple matching is not the same as in Python, PHP and .NET where `re.findall`, `preg_match_all` and `Regex.Matches` will test each position in the string (=advance the regex index) by themselves.